# Combine two varying size data sets in to one in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two data sets that are populated from two different tables which can vary in size as those tables change, and I'd like to combine them in to one set of data. I'm completely stumped on how to go about doing this, any ideas?

Please see example of data set 1 and 2, and how I'd like it to look in the right side data in the image :

[image: Two Data Sets]

The data used is as follows:

```
Data Set 1          Data Set 2          Data Set 1 & 2  
Employee    Start Date      Employee    Start Date      Employee    Start Date
Julie   01/12/2019      Lee 01/12/2019      Julie   01/12/2019
Daisy   01/12/2019      Anna    01/12/2019      Daisy   01/12/2019
Laura   01/12/2019      David   01/12/2019      Laura   01/12/2019
            Sam 01/12/2019      Lee 01/12/2019
            George  01/12/2019      Anna    01/12/2019
                        David   01/12/2019
                        Sam 01/12/2019
                        George  01/12/2019
```

Comment: If only Excel had an APPEND() function. Does your Excel version support LET() and SEQUENCE() spreadsheet functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on O365 then use `VSTACK()` formula.

```
=VSTACK(A3:B5,D3:E7)
```

If you data increase continuously then could try-

```
=VSTACK(FILTER(A3:B50000,A3:A50000<>""),FILTER(D3:E50000,D3:D50000<>""))
```

> ***Edit:*** If you do not have `VSTACK()` then go with `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTERXML()` like-

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A3:B20,D3:E20)&"</s></t>","//s"),INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(x)/2,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I'm on Excel Version 2102 (13801.21092) semi-annual enterprise and don't have `VSTACK()` as yet ...

Comment: I like this solution because it can handle duplicates. Upvoted

Comment: @DS_London Do you have `FILTER()` function?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns New Excel formulas are really amazing.

Comment: @Harun24hr I have LET,SEQUENCE,FILTER,UNIQUE,SORT etc, but not VSTACK as yet. My IT team control the updates.

Comment: @DS_London Nice! Then could use `=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A3:E20)&"</s></t>","//s"),INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(x)/2,2)))`.

Comment: Or `=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A3:B20,D3:E20)&"</s></t>","//s"),INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(x)/2,2)))` for different column, even from different sheet as well.

Comment: @Harun24hr Yes (as per my comment to the OP) ... but I'm not the OP ;-)

Comment: @DS_London Oh, sorry! I do not notice it.

Comment: hey @Harun24hr I actually need to increment the date of the second set of data by a day, is this easy to do when combining the data like this or should I look for another way?

Comment: The `VSTACK()` with `FILTER()` would be good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few more alternatives using `VSTACK()` & `UNIQUE()`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=UNIQUE(VSTACK(A2:B5,D2:E7))
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `J2`

```
=LET(rngOne,A2:B5,
rngTwo,D2:E7,
r,SEQUENCE(ROWS(rngOne)+ROWS(rngTwo)),
c,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(rngOne)),
output,IFERROR(INDEX(rngOne,r,c),INDEX(rngTwo,r-ROWS(rngOne),c)),
UNIQUE(output))
```

---

Edit: We can also accomplish this task using **Power Query** quite efficiently!

[image]

**Follow the steps:**

1. Convert the ranges into a table, select any cell on the range and press CTRL T, this will ask you check my table as headers,
2. Rename the table as `DataSetOne`, do the same for the second range and rename it as `DataSetTwo`
3. Goto `Data Tab`, From `Get & Transform`, click on `Get Data`, from `Other Sources` and click on `Blank Query`,
4. This opens the PQ editor,
5. Place the below `M-Code` in Advance Editor which you will find in Home Tab, (remove the M-code which shows for the blank query),

---

```
let
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataSetOne"]}[Content],
    DataTypeOne = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceOne,{{"Employee", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}}),
    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataSetTwo"]}[Content],
    DataTypeTwo = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceTwo,{{"Employee", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}}),
    Append = Table.Combine({DataTypeOne, DataTypeTwo})
in
    Append
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**If all workers are unique** (each worker appears just once and there is no common workers between datasets) you can do it easily with consolidate function. You can consolidate 2 or more datasets **as long as all of them share headers**:

> [Consolidate data in multiple
> worksheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b)

Notice consolidate is designed to resume data and get a numeric result, but because dates are numbers in Excel, you may use it for this:

[image]